# What should USERID be in a socks4 proxy connect message?

Tags: proxy

I would like to send a `connect` request to a `socks4` proxy server, which will connect me to another remote host. I've read the [socks4 protocol specification](https://www.openssh.com/txt/socks4.protocol), which provides this scheme for the `connect` message:

```
                +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+....+----+
                | VN | CD | DSTPORT |      DSTIP        | USERID       |NULL|
                +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+....+----+
 # of bytes:       1    1      2              4           variable       1
```

1. `VN` is version number, so it should be `4`.
2. `CD` should be `1` for `connect` request.
3. `DSTPORT` should be the remote host port.
4. `DSTIP` should be the remote host ip address.
5. `USERID`**? Says, it can be variable. But what value should I provide? Random? How long?**
6. `NULL` - terminator for the `USERID`. Byte of all zero bits.

I hope, I understood the protocol correctly in other things.

Comment: It's a standard C-style null-terminated string that corresponds to whatever the socks4 proxy is using for user authentication.  See the proxy configuration to determine what's needed.

Comment: if there is no authentication then I don't need to use it then, i guess. I'll try that right away, finishing up the script. Can I ask, how would a password be passed, then?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact use of USERID depends on the SOCKS4 server in question. It's a null-terminated string of variable length.

If the server doesn't require that field you can just use 0x00.

Comment: how can a password be provided for a SOCKS4 proxy? I understand, that the USERID serves as a username for the proxy server, but where is the password?

Comment: Since there's no provision for a password, my guess is that `USERID` is a shared secret between user and server.